# Scipy / Sympy to Optimize Multivariate System

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to replicate Excel's Goal Seek functional, which is based upon Newton-Raphson.

In my case, I'd like to optimize the rate of a group of people (including kids) to kids (group/kids) by a certain rate target of 'Z' to get the new number of kids; then reduce with group number with the change from the new kids number.

**Example**:
Say I have 1000 people in a group in including kids, which account for 100... Say my target rate is **12** (group / kids)... To work this out, I would need to decrease the kids to 76, which would also reduce the group to 923.

The pseudo formula would be Group (1000 - X) / X, though the X value in the denominator would need to be calculated first...

Code Attempt:

```
from scipy import optimize

# inputs
group = 1000
kids = 100

# formula
def f(x, group):
    results = (group - x) / x
    return results

optimize.newton(f, 100, 1000)
```

This bombs out with the args not passing through correctly, but I'm just not sure how to structure the equation.

Edit: adding that I'm not sure where to put the new target either... also clarifying that I want the result no lower than the target.

Comment: Do you want the value to be as close to target rate as possible? Or it should be no lower than target?

Comment: thanks for the clarifying question... No lower than the target. I'll add that back to the question :)

Comment: In that case 77 is wrong answer, since 923/77 ~ 11.987 < 12.

Comment: lol yup, you're right. So the # of kids would be around ~76

Answer (score 0):

You need only simple math to do so. Notice that:

```
(people - y) / y > target
```

Thus,

```
people - y > target * y
people > (target + 1) * y
people / (target + 1) > y
```

The number of kids that should be removed from group needs to satisfy

```
kids - floor(people / (target + 1))
```

In that case you get 24. Thus, the number of kids is equal to 76 and the number of adults is equal to  924. Thus, `924/76 ~ 12,16 > 12`.

Comment: @Christopher: it is unknown, but you can calculate it using your knowledge of the people count and the target rate.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution via https://github.com/DrTol/GoalSeek_Python

```
def GoalSeek(fun,goal,x0,fTol=0.0001,MaxIter=1000):
    # Goal Seek function of Excel
    #   via use of Line Search and Bisection Methods

    # Inputs
    #   fun     : Function to be evaluated
    #   goal    : Expected result/output
    #   x0      : Initial estimate/Starting point

    # Initial check
    if fun(x0)==goal:
        print('Exact solution found')
        return x0

    # Line Search Method
    step_sizes=np.logspace(-1,4,6)
    scopes=np.logspace(1,5,5)

    vFun=np.vectorize(fun)

    for scope in scopes:
        break_nested=False
        for step_size in step_sizes:

            cApos=np.linspace(x0,x0+step_size*scope,int(scope))
            cAneg=np.linspace(x0,x0-step_size*scope,int(scope))

            cA=np.concatenate((cAneg[::-1],cApos[1:]),axis=0)

            fA=vFun(cA)-goal

            if np.any(np.diff(np.sign(fA))):

                index_lb=np.nonzero(np.diff(np.sign(fA)))

                if len(index_lb[0])==1:

                    index_ub=index_lb+np.array([1])

                    x_lb=np.asscalar(np.array(cA)[index_lb][0])
                    x_ub=np.asscalar(np.array(cA)[index_ub][0])
                    break_nested=True
                    break
                else: # Two or more roots possible

                    index_ub=index_lb+np.array([1])

                    print('Other solution possible at around, x0 = ', np.array(cA)[index_lb[0][1]])

                    x_lb=np.asscalar(np.array(cA)[index_lb[0][0]])
                    x_ub=np.asscalar(np.array(cA)[index_ub[0][0]])
                    break_nested=True
                    break

        if break_nested:
            break
    if not x_lb or not x_ub:
        print('No Solution Found')
        return

    # Bisection Method
    iter_num=0
    error=10

    while iter_num<MaxIter and fTol<error:

        x_m=(x_lb+x_ub)/2
        f_m=fun(x_m)-goal

        error=abs(f_m)

        if (fun(x_lb)-goal)*(f_m)<0:
            x_ub=x_m
        elif (fun(x_ub)-goal)*(f_m)<0:
            x_lb=x_m
        elif f_m==0:
            print('Exact spolution found')
            return x_m
        else:
            print('Failure in Bisection Method')

        iter_num+=1

    return x_m
```

## Run the function

```
def fun(x):
    return (group - x) / x

print(GoalSeek(fun, goal, x0))
```